# Errors in Installing CoolProp and TESpy Python libraries (packages)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install CoolProp and Tespy libraries (Packages) in my Jupyter notebook. Firstly i was getting the following errors
***"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/***
***ERROR: Failed building wheel for CoolProp
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:***

After that I installed Microsoft visual C++ 2019 by clicking on the link given in the error prompt.
Now after installing the above installer I am facing the following problems

***ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:***

***c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\2925471\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tp1rp4je\coolprop_1b4e2eea5213485b9739752d46ec1d4f\tmp5aicspg0.cpp': Permission denied***

***ERROR: Failed building wheel for CoolProp***

The links of packages are given below,

https://tespy.readthedocs.io/en/main/
http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/Python/index.html

Please give any suggestion. Thanks in anticipation